# How can I allow <td> and <tr> tags in DOMPurify?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dompurify

I am using **DOMPurify** library in javascript file to prevent XSS attacks.

Here is the code.

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Online jQuery Editor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type = "module" src="myJS.js"></script>
      <h1>jQuery element Selector</h1>
      <k1 id="k1"></k1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myJS.js**

```
import DOMPurify from './purify.js';

$(document).ready(function() {
      var tanCols1 = ''
      for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){
          tanCols1 += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
          }
      console.log('original--> ', tanCols1)
      var clean_data = DOMPurify.sanitize(tanCols1, {ALLOWED_TAGS:['option', 'td', 'tr', 'a', 'table']})
      console.log('cleaned--> ', clean_data)
      $("#k1").append(clean_data)

   });
```

original-->  `<td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>`

cleaned-->  0123456789

**Expected Result**--> `<td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>`

How can I allow `<td>` and `<tr>` tags in DOMPurify??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior might be an annoyance, but it's expected. DOMPurify relies on JSDOM or the browser DOM internally, and td/tr/th are not valid unless inside a table. The string you're passing doesn't include the `table`, so the DOM just throws those tags away. See also [this](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/issues/606), [this](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/issues/415), [this](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/issues/733), and [other issues](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acure53%2FDOMPurify+th+td&type=issues) on the repo.

Comment: Thanks @Zac Anger, I just added <table> tag, it got fixed.